# Why NetBeans complains about PSR-1 violation when assigning returned value?

Tags: php, netbeans-8, psr-1

I have this code:

```
<?php

function f() {
    return 5;
}

$a = 5;
```

And I am using NetBeans 8.2 with PSR-1 compatibility check turned on. And I am getting this error:

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are not assigning a returned value. That would be `$a = f();`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php

Comment: @JHoffmann: Yes but even if I assign a value it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PSR-1 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) states that

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.) or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.) but SHOULD NOT do both.

This means if you have function or class definitions in a file, you shouldn't have code with [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) (like a variable assignment) outside these definitions within the same file.

So

```
function f() {
    return 5;
}
```

and

```
$a = 5;
```

should be separated into different files.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain why this has become a standard? What good is such separation?

Comment: If you consquently keep such separation, you can always be sure that pure class / function definition files will never change any state in your application. This makes the code reusable in other places as just including one such file won't interfere with the state of the including program (errors can appear due to possible naming conflicts etc).